# I have mp4 that won't play in Internet Explorer

Tags: cross-browser

I'm having major difficulty playing clips across browsers. Things work fine in Chrome and Safari and Firefox but not at all in IE

http://kendallproductions.com/autism_clip.html

Loading the player...


    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "/videoclips/autism1.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg"
    });

Thanks

Comment: try an object tag in your HTML and you may want to put it on a dedicated video server like youtube and let the object tag refer to that.

Comment: thanks. added tag, got two videos on page. where should tag be inserted in code?

Comment: it should replace your existing div with the video

Comment: No change. http://kendallproductions.com/index.htm. Thank you.

Comment: well the only other things I can think of is the file type may not be supported or the SRC is incorrect.

Comment: there is now a video tag with html5 I would suggest trying that